# How to abstract away the interface to two similar classes?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I'm writing an [Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_tic-tac-toe) engine as a programming exercise (for myself, not homework) and I have two similar classes. One is a class `MiniBoard` that contains a single normal Tic-Tac-Toe board, and another `Board` that is itself a large Tic-Tac-Toe board conisiting of 9 `MiniBoards`, one for each large cell in the game.

I also have a function `int getState( ... )` that returns a certain number depending on whether a board is won, lost, drawn or in-progress. Since there is obvious symmetry between `MiniBoard` and `Board` it appears to me that I should be able to make my `getState` function accept both `MiniBoard` and `Board` as an argument, afterall they both must be either won, drawn, lost or in-progress.

At first I thought to make `Board` inherit from `MiniBoard`, but this approach turned out unnecessarily complicated because the functionality of `MiniBoard` is fundamentally different from `Board`, even though they do represent very similar objects. It also doesn't really follow the "IS A" relationship of OOP inheritance.

The idea that I currently have, but don't know if is any good, is to make an abstract base class `BaseBoard` that defines the common properties and methods as virtual and then have `Board` and `MiniBoard` derive from `BaseBoard`. Then I would define my function for getting the state as:

```
int getState(const BaseBoard &board)
```

The main issue I have with this approach is that I don't know upfront what kinds of properties and methods will I need for my BaseBoard down the line. And if I ever get the the point of having a large chain of inheritance that starts with BaseBoard and wanting to change something, that would mean I would have to change every class definition down the chain of inheritance. What is the solution to this issue? Just derive more classes?

All in all, is this a good way to solve the problem? And what are the pros and cons? I'm not very familiar with abstract base classes in C++. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but in the example given, why not make `getState` into a pure `virtual` member function of `BaseBoard`? Since it requires knowledge of the internal state of the `BaseBoard`-derived class it probably should be a member rather than a free function.

Comment: I agree that it's an interesting idea to make it a member function, I haven't thought of that. But is it a good idea to have a virtual member function that takes it's own class as an argument type? It seems convoluted.

Comment: That's the beauty of it. There's no need to pass anything in. When you invoke a member function on an object, the instance is automatically passed in as `this` .  `int BaseBoard::getState() const` is very nearly (and often implemented behind the scenes as) `int getState(const BaseBoard * this)`

Comment: @user4581301 But that just forces me to write two different implementations of the `getState` function, one for `BaseBoard` and one for `Board`. This can be done without any need for abstract base classes. I was hoping to somehow avoid that in an elegant way.

Comment: You may want to study *Composite* object-oriented design pattern. There, you get a part and the whole having the same interface.

Comment: If the rules are such that `Board` and `MiniBoard`'s state resolution logic is exactly the same, then you're right. Remove the `virtual` and make it a plain old member function of `BaseBoard`, but I suspect there will be differences. I'd have to see how you do the job to be sure.

Comment: Anyway, I'm dragging us off topic. What you've described in the question makes sense if you do it in a sensible manner, and the only way to know if you did it sensibly is to see how you did it.

Comment: Totally unrelated: Since your states are won, lost, drawn, or in-progress, consider using an `enum class` instead of an `int`. It will make the code easier to read and possibly allow the compiler to pick off some accidents for you.

Comment: I think that's a valid OOP approach. Factorizing the two classes into one common one (abstract class or interface) and then deriving the specifics of MiniBoard and Board.

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no right solution. It all depends on the context and what you want to do. Things that might be right in once instance might cause a lot of complications in another.

Yes, having both classes inherit from a BaseBoard is a solution. You'll likely have to deal with virtual functions (might be slightly slower than other solutions). I wouldn't set out to build a large inheritance chain if it's not making a lot of sense in the project. This would force some consistency between the APIs of the two objects. Here might be fine, but in some cases the two classes might be just too different. Usually a good hint that this is not the right approach is if you need multiple bases to get things working.

Another option is to have adaptors. Classes that would bring the interfaces to something reasonable. They would only delegate to the real classes (so slight performance hit). You would only have to do them for the classes that need to be passed to GetState so maybe not everything. This is a bit big on boilerplate as you keep writing almost the same code for every class.

Yet another option is to use templates. Some developers have a phobia of them. It would allow you to pass any class in as long as they implement the interface used (the methods called in the function). This is a bit hard to read since the interface is implicit and the errors might look a bit unfriendly. However this is usually very fast as the compiler can inline function calls if it wants.

If you're doing it as an exercise maybe try them all out and see for yourself how they work out.